# Can't Install Ambari service on Cluster

Tags: proxy, hortonworks-data-platform, azure-hdinsight, ambari

I cannot add the keyserver for Hortonworks repository like in their documentation: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/Ambari-2.7.1.0/bk_ambari-installation/content/download_the_ambari_repo_ubuntu16.html
I receive the following error:

```
apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B9733A7A07513CAD

Executing: /tmp/tmp.x2atUw3zqB/gpg.1.sh --recv-keys
--keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
B9733A7A07513CAD
gpg: requesting key 07513CAD from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key B9733A7A07513CAD can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver helper general error
gpg: keyserver communications error: unknown pubkey algorithm
gpg: keyserver receive failed: unknown pubkey algorithm
```

I tried also this command with the same result:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver-options https-proxy=http://ip:port --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://ip:port --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com B9733A7A07513CAD

Executing: /tmp/tmp.N5FIhVOT5y/gpg.1.sh --keyserver-options
https-proxy=http://ip:port
--keyserver-options
http-proxy=http://ip:port
--recv-keys
--keyserver
keyserver.ubuntu.com
B9733A7A07513CAD
gpg: requesting key 07513CAD from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpgkeys: key B9733A7A07513CAD can't be retrieved
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
gpg: keyserver communications error: keyserver helper general error
gpg: keyserver communications error: unknown pubkey algorithm
gpg: keyserver receive failed: unknown pubkey algorithm
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally successfully added the key with the following command template.

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver-options http-proxy="http:// : @ : " --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 07513ACD
```

My command:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver-options https-proxy=http://ip:port --keyserver-options http-proxy=http://ip:port --recv-keys --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv B9733A7A07513CAD

Executing: /tmp/tmp.a5ctOrZAWP/gpg.1.sh --keyserver-options
https-proxy=http://ip:port
--keyserver-options
http-proxy=http://ip:port
--recv-keys
--keyserver
hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80
--recv
B9733A7A07513CAD
gpg: requesting key 07513CAD from hkp server keyserver.ubuntu.com
gpg: key 07513CAD: public key "Jenkins (HDP Builds) <jenkin@hortonworks.com>" imported
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1  (RSA: 1)
```

Comment: So that was a connectivity issue (you should use HTTP proxy)

Comment: Not only the HTTP proxy, I had to add for keyserver option the hkp:// scheme and the port :80